# Kotlin data class coming from serialized json become a LinkedHashTreeMap

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, moshi

So, i have an `Android Room` entity that have a properties which is a list of a data class. Like this:

```
   @ColumnInfo(name = "titles")
   val titles: List<AnimeTitleEntity>,
```

And I'm using a type converter to handle this by converthing this value from list of data class into `JSON` and vice versa with `Moshi`.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class AnimeTitleEntity(

    @Json(name = "type")
    val type: String,

    @Json(name = "title")
    val title: String
)
```

```
import util.fromJson as MoshiFromJson

internal class AnimeTitlesConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromJson(json: String): List<AnimeTitleEntity> {
        return MoshiFromJson<List<AnimeTitleEntity>>(json) ?: emptyList()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toJson(titles: List<AnimeTitleEntity>): String {
        return MoshiToJson(titles)
    }
}
```

```
val KotlinMoshi: Moshi = Moshi
        .Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
```

```
inline fun <reified T> fromJson(data: String): T? {
    val adapter = KotlinMoshi.adapter(T::class.java)
    return adapter.fromJson(data)
}
```

I can fetch this normally from room, and do some logging, and the app didn't even throw an error or crash if i don't do anything to this model like converting them into another model. But the problem starts happening when I'm trying to map this, and when I log the data type of the properties its actually a `linkedHashMap`. So, `Room` never really return a list of the data class but not having an error.

> Entity type: class com.squareup.moshi.LinkedHashTreeMap

How can this happen while not causing error? Because the property should be a list of data class and not `LinkedHashTreeMap`. And what is the solution for this?

Comment: Post your full AnimeTitleEntity class.